# Which word order is correct?

Tags: grammar, word-order

Which sentence is correct:

> Regarding extra expenses, what **should I** do?

or

> Regarding extra expenses, what **I should** do?

Comment: The first seems fine, the second is incorrect.

Comment: When you construct questions, the subject-verb order is reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is correct

> Regarding extra expenses, what should I do?

Comment: You can also add "is it" to result in: "Regarding extra expenses, what is it I should do?"   This is similar to the second form.